# Converted MP4 video file to H.264, but there is no sound

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have an MP4 video file. I'm turning this into H.264. After converting, the video looks good, but there is no sound. Can you help me?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.h264
```

Comment: What do you *actually* want to do? This seems like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 4):

`.264` represents a raw H264 bitstream so no audio will be present. If you want the video in `input` to be transcoded to a H264 stream, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4
```

But check if it is already H264. Run `ffprobe input.mp4`.

Comment: But this time it appears to be mp4. I want to see it as h.264. Is not there a way to do this?

Comment: @siklopentan: H.264 and MP4 are different classes entirely – one is a codec, the other a container holding codecs. So a file could be **both at the same time.** (And probably is.)